# How do i sort listbox items from a txt file by numbers c#

Tags: c#

I want to know how to i sort the items i have in my listbox from a txt file by the lowest number to the highest?

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

In my txt file

```
    Shirt = 10$
    pants = 20$
    shoes = 60$
    hat = 10$
    socks = 5$
```

Comment: You need to split or isolate the value from the item so you can sort by the number.  You probably need to do this anyway if you will be doing any math such as 3 shirts = 30.  Research databinding to a List<T> and get rid of those empty catch blocks.  Also read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: Create a model  with properties  Name, Cost and then populate model with txt file values.  later you can apply sorting on Cost properties

Comment: `foreach(var line in lines.OrderBy(l => Convert.ToInt32(l.Split('=')[1].TrimEnd('$'))))
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}`

Answer (score 1):

you must seperate string and number in dicionary then orderby on numbers

```
 Dictionary<string, int> dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            string[] str = line.Split('=');
            var num= str[1].Replace("$",""); // for seperate $ and number
            dic.Add(str[0], (Convert.ToInt32(num)));
        }
        foreach(var sortItem in dic.OrderBy(x=>x.Value))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(sortItem .Key + " = "+ sortItem .Value.ToString() + "$");
        }
```

output is :

```
socks  = 5$
Shirt  = 10$
 hat  = 10$
pants  = 20$
shoes  = 60$
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use linq to perform this operation:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Professionals\POC\linQ\linQ\DataFile.txt", Encoding.UTF8);

        if (lines.Count() > 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> listIndex = lines.ToDictionary(
                                                                   x => x.Split('=')[0].Trim(), 
                                                                   x => (x.Contains("$") ? Convert.ToInt32(x.Split('=')[1].Replace("$", "")) : 0)
                                                                   );
            listIndex = listIndex.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            if (listIndex != null && listIndex.Count > 0)
            {
                //---your code 
            }
        }
```